# How to detect defect in edge in python?

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

I want to check the edge of fruits and detect the defect in it. I detected the edge using canny edge detection algorithm using opencv. But how can I train the machine to identify the defect in fruits like apple,lemon? Like a rotten fruit has defected edge as compared to a fresh fruit. I want machine to identify it. How it can be done? [This is the code of edge detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vifL.png)

[This is the edge of fresh apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk1eQ.png)

[And this is the edge of rotten apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMy5T.png)

Comment: Hi Radhika, welcome to stackoverflow. I think your question is too general for this site-- we can help with specific programming tasks that you will formulate by narrowing down the steps of what you need to do. You must have received some instructions. But at least you can replace the **image** of your code with the actual code-- images of code are really disliked around here since we can't do anything with them.

Comment: @alexis thank you for your reply. I was actually trying to put the code in the question but it showed some errors, that's why I had to upload the image.

Comment: @alexis import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('rotten.jpg',0)
edges = cv.Canny(img,100,200)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()                                                                                                                                   This is the code that i have used. The task that I have is to detect the defect in usual edge

Comment: 1. Put the code in the question, not in comments. 2. Fix the problems. Start by pasting your code, highlighting all of it, and pressing the `{}` button in the toolbar. It will indent your code block by 4 spaces, and then it will display correctly.

Comment: Anyway I just looked at your code, all it does is display some jpgs in a grid. There is no edge detection performed. I think you need to go back and study your assignment more carefully.

Comment: Checking based on edges might not be the best idea. You lose all color information.

Comment: @alexis ok..I will checkit once again.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have done thecolorpart already.Now I want to go for edge. So converting it into gray is not a problem now.